# Set Font Size for HFONT using DEFAULT_GUI_FONT

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, fonts, dialog

In my dialog I set the font to the default GUI font, however I do need to manually set the font size to 15. 
How can I do that?

```
HFONT   myQueryFont;
myQueryFont = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
// set font size here
SendMessage(this->hwndQuery,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)myQueryFont,FALSE);
```

Comment: `GetObject`, adjust `LOGFONT` structure to taste, `CreateFontIndirect`

Comment: Elaborate? And please don't downvote without providing a useful answer. I couldn't find a proper working example anywhere with what you describe.

Comment: `LOGFONT` structure describes all aspects of the font, each aspect in a separate field. In particular, `LOGFONT::lfHeight` determines font size. `GetObject(fontHandle)` fills in `LOGFONT` structure with the information about the font represented by the handle. `CreateFontIndirect` takes filled-in `LOGFONT` as a parameter, and creates a font object matching the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to use `DEFAULT_GUI_FONT`. [`DEFAULT_GUI_FONT` is a relic of the past.](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/07/07/436435.aspx)

Unfortunately, there is no real way to get "the" system standard font on Windows. There are several issues at play here: internationalization, the shell/dialog manager and its fake fonts (`MS Shell Dlg`), Vista changing the default point size from 8 to 9, etc...

Your best bet is to get the message-box font and use that. It's provided as a `LOGFONT` via the `SystemParametersInfo()` `SPM_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS` function.

(I need to talk about this when I update [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130548/proper-way-to-get-the-preferred-size-of-windows-controls) with new findings.)