# Windows API - UI layout sizing/spacing guideline inconsistencies

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I've been trying to make an application that follows the guidelines on layout as outlined here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742486.aspx#sizingandspacing

I'm converting from DLUs to pixels using GetTextExtentPoint32 and my results are consistent with the ones found here:
http://metalkin.egloos.com/m/4269163

These results however are not consistent with the guidelines. A command button with a DLU size of 50 x 14 ends up being 75 x 26 in pixels instead of the 75 x 23 (73 x 21 plus a 1 pixel invisible border - a fairly common button size in windows applications, it seems) listed in the guidelines.
When using the DLU dimensions for text boxes there is too much padding below the text.

Am I missing something, or are the guidelines basically useless?

Comment: Doesn't directly answer your question, but MSDN suggests using [`MapDialogRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645502(v=vs.85).aspx) for cases where you know the size in DLUs already.

Comment: Looks like the MSDN article was first written for 8pt text, then updated for Vista without also updating the pixel sizes.  That happens.  The days you could count on sizes in pixels to be reproducible have been fast disappearing anyway so don't worry about it.

Comment: Are you using Segoe UI 9? Because if I recall correctly the numbers are not for Segoe UI 9; they're for the previous default (I forget if it was size 8 or size 8.5). (I still need t update [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130548/proper-way-to-get-the-preferred-size-of-windows-controls) with the details.) [I wrote a program that you can use to experiment more readily with all this.](https://github.com/andlabs/windlgunits)

Comment: @Peter Torr From what I've gathered this function only works when you've used the CreateDialog to make your ui elements.

Comment: @andlabs Yes. I tried again with Segoe UI pt 8 and I was able to get the same pixel dimensions as in the guidelines.  

`@Hans` It seems to be true, but only for some of the UI elements. I guess they kept some of the old calculations and added new ones using a different font.  

The major problem for me is that the text boxes for instance don't look right when using the default font with the recommended DLU sizes. The problem only seems to get worse the larger the font you use (too much padding at the bottom of the text as noted in the original question).

Comment: Right, I've noticed the text box thing too. I'm genuinely unsure of what to do about that, though :S It doesn't help that different programs that come with Windows both corroborate and contradict the results with hand calculations. Lord knows what Visual Studio's GUI editor did... (or what the List View control did) I know another thing, though: to get the three DLUs down from the top of the neighboring control thing that labels have to be descended to, you also have to take into consideration `TEXTMETRIC.tmInternalLeading`.

Comment: Just do what looks good. Microsoft don't follow their own style guide, I don't see why anyone else should :)